# how to measure the Shape margin in vba

Tags: vba, shapes, powerpoint, margins

When you export a shape as image in powerpoint sometimes it generates a white space. As can be seen in this image (with the white font of this webpage cannot be seen but if you download it and open you will see). I need to position this image in a exact place but with this margins I cannot control it well. I need a way to measure those margins to take them in count or it would be even better if I have a way to remove them.

Right now I am measuring how big it is using the following code lines:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
    Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
          ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
          ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
#End If

 'here I store the height and width
 Hght = GetImageDimensions("c:\dink_template\dinkFile\sizeimage.jpg")(0)
 wdt = GetImageDimensions("c:\dink_template\dinkFile\sizeimage.jpg")(1)

Public Function GetImageDimensions(filePath As String) As Variant
'Function returns an array of (Height, Width) from a specific image file path
Dim ImgSize(0 To 1) As Long
'returning picture.width in OLE_YSIZE_HIMETRIC/OLE_XSIZE_HIMETRIC
' these are representing 0.01 mm
With LoadPicture(filePath)
    ImgSize(0) = .height / 2540 * (1440 / TwipsPerPixelY())
    ImgSize(1) = .width / 2540 * (1440 / TwipsPerPixelX())
End With
GetImageDimensions = ImgSize
End Function




Const HWND_DESKTOP As Long = 0
Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88
Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

'--------------------------------------------------
Public Function TwipsPerPixelX() As Single
'--------------------------------------------------
'Returns the width of a pixel, in twips.
'--------------------------------------------------
  Dim lngDC As Long
  lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)
  TwipsPerPixelX = 1440& / GetDeviceCaps(lngDC, LOGPIXELSX)
  ReleaseDC HWND_DESKTOP, lngDC
End Function

'--------------------------------------------------
Public Function TwipsPerPixelY() As Single
'--------------------------------------------------
'Returns the height of a pixel, in twips.
'--------------------------------------------------
  Dim lngDC As Long
  lngDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP)
  TwipsPerPixelY = 1440& / GetDeviceCaps(lngDC, LOGPIXELSY)
  ReleaseDC HWND_DESKTOP, lngDC
End Function
```

I compare the height and width that I get from this values with the ones that I get with shape.height and shape.width and get how big is the margin. But I need to know the margin that I have in the left and in the right, in the top and in the bottom.

[image]

Comment: in which way you export your shape? by using `.export method`? have you tried with `shapes().TextFrame2.MarginBottom` and other similar margin properties?

Comment: Yes I already try with them. I set all to 0 but the white margin is still appearing